# Is every weakly $1$-dimensional space embeddable in the plane?

Tags: gn.general-topology, plane-geometry, metric-spaces, dimension-theory, embeddings

A $1$-dimensional (separable metric) space $X$ is **weakly $1$-dimensional** if $$\Lambda(X)=\{x\in X:X\text{ is 1-dimensional at }x\}$$
is zero-dimensional (i.e. the space $\Lambda(X)$ has a basis of clopen sets).

**Question.** Does every weakly $1$-dimensional space embed into the plane?

Of course every $1$-dimensional space embeds into $\mathbb R^3$, and my sense is that weakly $1$-dimensional spaces are small enough to embed into $\mathbb R ^2$.

In the following paper there is constructed a universal weakly $1$-dimensional space $E$.

*van Mill, Jan; Pol, Roman*, [**Note on weakly (n)-dimensional spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s006050170056), Monatsh. Math. 132, No. 1, 25-33 (2001). [ZBL0988.54036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0988.54036).

Thus in the question it is necessary and sufficient to consider only the space $E$. It is difficult to tell at first glance whether $E$ is planar, as its construction involves the hyperspace of the Hilbert cube (!).

Comment: I don't know the terminology you are using, but wouldn't all graphs be weakly 1-dimensional, and graphs generally do not embed in the plane.

Comment: @RyanBudney A graph cannot be weakly $1$-dimensional because to be $1$-dimensional it must have an edge, which would be contained in $\Lambda(X)$, and then $\Lambda(X)$ is also $1$-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks, I see I misread your definition.